# multivariate optimization in python

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

anyone please let me know how to solve multivariate problems in python. The objective function is given in picture 1 and few constraints in picture 2

[Objective function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqsTQ.png)

[Constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdLc3.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking how to solve a linear [integer programming problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) in python. You could use [Pyomo](http://pyomo.org), [PuLP](https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/) or [python-MIP](https://www.python-mip.com/) to model your optimization problem and solve it with a suitable solver of your choice. [Gurobi](http://www.gurobi.com/) and [Cplex](https://www.ibm.com/de-de/marketplace/ibm-ilog-cplex) are common commercial solvers (both offering a free academic-licence) while [GLPK](https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/), [SCIP](https://www.scipopt.org/index.php) or [CBC](https://github.com/coin-or/Cbc) are common used non-commercial ones.